# Dotcms Installation

Tags: tomcat, dotcms

After spending hours of developing my website through dotCMS, now it's the time to upload it in a server (the server of course supports tomcat). My question is that should I have to upload both the War file and the database (through .sql file) in the server?

Comment: Are you trying to install from source or from the distribution zip file?  Unless you're using glassfish or jboss there isn't really a reason to be using the WAR file in my opinion

Comment: I downloaded dotcms distribution zip file (dotcms_3.0.1.zip) three months ago and I was working on it in order to develop my website. Some days ago I finished with the development and I want to upload the app in a server that runs tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You should tar up the entire dotCMS installation and do a DB dump and move both to your production environment.  If you have an existing system running on prod either (a) spin up new servers and use them to replace prod or (b) setup dotCMS on product for now to use a different port other than 80 and verify it all looks great once setting up the files and DB on production.

1) Once it's ready to flip the switch, change the tomcat config to use port 80.

2) Turn off current web deployment

3) Restart dotCMS and it will bring up port 80.

The WAR file is really made for deploying on systems like Glassfish, jBoss, WebSphere etc.  I would highly recommend if using tomcat to use the tomcat that comes with dotCMS since it's "tweaked" for prime dotCMS usage